# insertar datos a traves de un For

Tags: sql-server, bucle-for, asp

estoy insertando datos a traves de un ciclo For en asp con sqlserver, pero me esta generando errores como al insertar la cantidad que debería me inserta uno mas y duplicando el ultimo, o solo me ingresa un solo dato y los datos que llegan no son los que corresponden.  Tengo las siguientes variables que recibo por post

```
    total = Request.Form("total")
    sa1 = Request.Form("sa1")
    productos1 = Request.Form("productos1")
    nw_valor3 = Request.Form("cantidad1")
    nw_valor4 = Request.Form("costo1")
    sa2 = Request.Form("sa2")
    productos2 = Request.Form("productos2")
    cantidad2 = Request.Form("cantidad2")
    costo2 = Request.Form("costo2")
    sa3 = Request.Form("sa3")
    productos3 = Request.Form("productos3")
    cantidad3 = Request.Form("cantidad3")
    costo3 = Request.Form("costo3")
    ......
    sa10 = Request.Form("sa10")
    productos10 = Request.Form("productos10")
    cantidad10 = Request.Form("cantidad10")
    costo10 = Request.Form("costo10")

    sSQL="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id='" & ID & "'"
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then

    Else

        For i=1 To Request.Form("total").Count

          sSQL= "insert into productos(sa, producto, cantidad,costo) values ('" & sa&(i) & "', '" & productos&(i) & "', '" & cantidad&(i) & "', '" & costo&(i) & "')"
          Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQL)

        Next
   End If
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto no me toma los valores que deberia y solo me arroja por resultado 1 fila.

Como puedo solucionar este error, porque algo debo estar haciendo mal que esto no se me ejecuta como deberia y guardar los datos dependiendo del total que he mandado seleccionado anteriormente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira, prueba de esta manera, yo tuve el mismo problema y logre solucionarlo asi

```
For i2=0 To Request.Form("total").Count -1
                    For i = 1 To Request.Form("total")
                        sa = Request.Form("sa"&i)
                        productos = Request.Form("productos"&i)
                        cantidad = Request.Form("cantidad"&i)
                        costo = Request.Form("costo"&i)

                            sSQL = "insert into productos(sa, producto, cantidad,costo) VALUES('" & sa & "','" & productos & "', '" & cantidad &"', '" & costo & "')"
                            Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQL)

                    Next    
                Next
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba